# XHR not showing in network tab

Tags: python, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to web scrape recommendation information from yahoo finance - https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/STNE?p=STNE

Before page loading, I open network tab and filter 'XHR' to find API details. I could not find the  following API in my chrome. By googling I found the following API is used to fetch details related to recommendations.

```
https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v10/finance/quoteSummary/STNE?formatted=true&crumb=swg7qs5y9UP&lang=en-US&region=US&modules=financialData,recommendationTrend&corsDomain=finance.yahoo.com
```

I am wondering how others could found the above API. What's the right way to find API info? I can see the below one in my network tab but this does not return the details related to recommendation.

https://query2.finance.yahoo.com/v7/finance/quote?symbols=STNE&fields=exchangeTimezoneName,exchangeTimezoneShortName,regularMarketTime,gmtOffSetMilliseconds&region=US&lang=en-US